# how to process multiple uploads using perl?

Tags: perl, file-upload, cgi, multifile-uploader, file-processing

I am struck at this point since 1 day.
First am taking all file names .Then upload and collect all file handles.
Due to some reason, files are not uploading into /home/img folder correctly.
If uploaded, they are getting corrupted. Corrupted filesize shows as 0 bytes or 24 bytes.

Please provide assistance with upload part.

```
#!/usr/bin/perlml -Tw

use strict;
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
my $cgi = CGI->new;

my $upload_dir = "/home/img";

my @raw_filenames       = $cgi->param('photos');
my $filename_characters = 'a-zA-Z0-9_.-';
my $ext                 = "";

my $raw_filenames = "";
my $raw_fh        = "";

my $single_filename  = "";
my $single_io_handle = "";

my @all_io_handle = "";
my @all_filenames = "";

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

#Getting the filenames ready
foreach $raw_filenames (@raw_filenames) {
    ( $single_filename, undef, $ext ) = fileparse( $raw_filenames, qr{\..*} );
    push( @all_filenames, "$single_filename" );
}

#This prints the ready list of filenames
print "@all_filenames\n <br>";

#Getting the filehandles ready
my @raw_fh = $cgi->upload('photos');

foreach $raw_fh (@raw_fh) {
    $single_io_handle = $raw_fh->handle;
    push( @all_io_handle, "$single_io_handle" );
}

#This prints the ready list of filehandles
print "@all_io_handle\n <br>";
```

Comment: Time to debug:  Are you able to create a form to upload a single file successfully?  Confirm that first.  Then see if you can create a form that has multiple upload fields with unique names.  Confirm that works.  Finally, give all the upload fields the same name like you're trying here.  This might isolate the problem to a smaller scope and therefore help with determining the issue.

Comment: I know nothing about `CGI` uploads, but wondering why you didn't use some higher level and more modern framework, like: Poet, Mojolicious, Dancer and such... Many things are much simpler, easier and faster to develop-deploy...

Comment: @Miller - Yes. i am able to create a form with 
`code` <form action="myperl.pl" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> with input multiple attribute.

Comment: The CGI module is looking rather long in the tooth these days. Check out CGI::Alternatives on CPAN to see more modern (and easier!) ways to do what you're trying to accomplish with cgi here.

Comment: @Miller I will try using the method you said. I will get back again.

Comment: @Miller -its fine when uploading single file or uploading files with different input fields. Going wrong when uploading multiple files in same field.

Comment: Can you post your html form, too, in case there is an error in that?

Comment: ` 
<form action="myperl.pl" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<input type="file" name="photos" accept="image/gif,image/jpeg" multiple required>
<input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>`
- @ialarmedalien

Comment: And what browser are you using?

Comment: chrome and mozilla-@ialarmedalien

Comment: Have you checked $cgi->error for any error messages? What version of CGI.pm are you using?

I would HIGHLY recommend that you use something else--as the docs for CGI.pm say, "The rational for this decision is that CGI.pm is no longer considered good practice for developing web applications, including quick prototyping and small web scripts. There are far better, cleaner, quicker, easier, safer, more scalable, more extensible, more modern alternatives available at this point in time. These will be documented with CGI::Alternatives."

Answer (score 0):

The following test of [`CGI->upload`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI#Processing-a-file-upload-field) works with [html input multiple](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_multiple.asp) attribute.

I attempt to view the file size of each uploaded file both by the temp file and by reading it from disk:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);

my $q = CGI->new();

my $msg = '';
if ( $q->request_method() eq 'POST' ) {
    $msg .= '<table border=1 cellpadding=3 cellspacing=0><tr><th>File name</th><th>Temp size</th><th>Slurped size</th></tr>';
    for my $file ( $q->upload('myfile') ) {
        my $tempsize = -s $q->tmpFileName($file);
        my $readsize = do {
            my $fh = $file->handle();
            binmode $fh;
            local $/;    # Slurp entire file
            length <$fh>;
        };
        $msg .= '<tr><td>' . $q->escapeHTML($file) . "</td><td>$tempsize</td><td>$readsize</td></tr>";
    }
    $msg .= '</table>';
}

print $q->header;

print <<"END_HTML";
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload form using CGI</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Upload form using CGI</h1>
$msg
@{[ $q->start_form() ]}
<p><input type="file" name="myfile" accept="image/gif,image/jpeg,image/png" multiple required /></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Upload"></p>
@{[ $q->end_form() ]}
</body>
</html>
END_HTML
```

**Before Posting**:

> [image: Before Post]

**After Posting 3 images**:

> [image: After Post]

It's possible that you simple have an outdated version of `CGI`.  Check the version

```
$ perl -MCGI -E 'say $CGI::VERSION'
4.04
```